# Сдача Associate Android Developer сертификата от Google, в чем суть?

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

Недавно попался на глаза сайт где рассказывали про этот сертификат. Почитал про сдачу, про то как это все происходит и возникли сразу вопросы. Во-первых имеет ли вообще смысл парится и пытаться сдать? С одной стороны это конечно круто, сертификат от Google и все такое, но может он не очень помогает при трудоустройстве. Во-вторых какие знания нужно иметь чтобы его сдать. На текущий момент я сижу над проектом в котором используеться библиотека Retrofit и все что с ней связано. То есть тянуть данные с сервера и дальше уже их как-то отображать, послать запрос на сервер тоже не проблема. Но что-то мне кажется этого не хватит для сдачи этого экзамена и я не знаю нужно ли вообще начинать что-то учить именно для сдачи этого экзамена. Если кто-то уже имел опыт сдачи или уже имеет подобный сертификат, то буду рад если поделитесь какой-то информацией.

Comment: Для устройства на работу помогут только структуры, алгоритмы, перестановки, деревья, хэш и прочее. Остальное лирика :( Я бы попарился ради ачивки для себя только и все, а где сайт то?)

Comment: то есть сертификат этот чисто для себя сдается?

Comment: экзамен платный :) https://medium.com/@multidots/how-to-clear-associate-android-developer-exam-ab3ae5d783b7. В общем за бугром может бы это и выгорело, а у нас за классику все таки (могу ошибаться)

Comment: что значит за бугром выгорело? типа он не очень влияет на трудоустройство и все такое?